# ML currying and anonymous functions

Tags: sml, currying

Could someone please explain to me what is going on in these three bindings?
What is the significance of the parens? What is the meaning of g and why does it have to be a g as an argument in the anonymous function? And overall what is actually happening in all of this... Thank you!

```
val a = fn g => (fn x => fn y => x) (g 0) (g 7);
val b = fn g => (fn x => fn y => x) (g 0) (g "happy");
val c = fn g => (fn x => fn y => x) (g 0) (g (g 7));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `(fn x => fn y => x)` is the [constant function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_function). It takes two arguments (`x` and `y`) and always returns the first argument (i.e. `x`).

This function is applied to two arguments in all three functions `a`, `b` and `c`:

1. In `a` the constant function is applied to `(g 0)` and `(g 7)`.
2. In `b` the constant function is applied to `(g 0)` and `(g "happy")`.
3. In `c` the constant function is applied to `(g 0)` and `(g (g 7))`.

In all three cases, the result is `(g 0)` because the second argument is discarded. Therefore, all the three functions can be simplified to:

```
val a = fn g => g 0
val b = fn g => g 0
val c = fn g => g 0
```

Actually, the second function (i.e. `b`) raises a type error because `g` is first applied to an `int` and later applied to a `string`.

Although the functions `a` and `c` have the same result yet they do not have the same type:

1. The type of `a` is `(int -> 'a) -> 'a` because we don't know the return type of the function `g`. Hence, it is a polymorphic function and it's more general than `c`.
2. The type of `c` is `(int -> int) -> int` because `g` is applied to its own result (i.e. `g` is applied to `(g 7)`). Hence, its return type must be the same as its argument type (i.e. `int`).

Therefore, `a` is more general than `c` and every instance of `c` can be safely replaced with `a` but not vice versa.